# Change href of Live Status link in Wagtail Admin

Tags: wagtail

I made a one page scrolling site using wagtail. I have a homepage model and everything else is child pages such as about us, events, etc. On the admin page it creates a slug with the title of the child page which is what the live status link uses. For example it is `<a href="/about-us/">`. Is there a way to change the live status link at all?

Answer (score 2):

The page URL is constructed by calling the `get_url_parts` method on the page model - by overriding this method, you can customise the resulting URL:

- http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.wagtailcore.models.Page.get_url_parts
- http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/pages.html#customising-url-patterns-for-a-page-model

Normally, if you're overriding `get_url_parts`, you'd want to make a corresponding customisation to your site's URL routing behaviour, to ensure that the page is actually available at the URL in question; this can be done with [RoutablePageMixin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html). In this case, though, it sounds like you're just using these subpages as placeholders for page content, and aren't bothered about them being accessible at their own URL - so you can get away with simply returning '/' as the page path:

```
class MyChildPage(Page):
    # ...
    def get_url_parts(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url_parts = super(MyChildPage, self).get_url_parts(*args, **kwargs)

        if url_parts is None:
            # in this case, the page doesn't have a well-defined URL in the first place -
            # for example, it's been created at the top level of the page tree
            # and hasn't been associated with a site record
            return None

        site_id, root_url, page_path = url_parts

        # return '/' in place of the real page path
        return (site_id, root_url, '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this question when using Wagtail as a headless CMS for a Gatsby site. As I do use the URLs generated by Wagtail to structure the Gatsby site, redefining the `get_url_parts` method does not help me. I do want to keep the page URL as is and use a different host when clicking on the "View Live" or "Live" button in the admin.

I found that overriding the `serve()` method of the pages that you want to be served by a different host allows you to do just that.

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class BlogPage(Page):
    ...
    def serve(self, request):
        site_id, site_root, relative_page_url = self.get_url_parts(request)
        return redirect('http://localhost:8001' + relative_page_url)
```

In the code above, the serve method of the `BlogPage` model is overridden to use the `request` and the `get_url_parts` method to extract the requested `relative_page_url` (that is relative to the site root -- in development that would be `http://localhost`). Since my frontend keeps the same URL structure as the Wagtail site, I just use the extracted `relative_page_url` and combine it with the host of the frontend (in this development case `localhost:8001`) and return a redirect response (generated with `django.shortcuts.redirect`) to that full URL.

It probably makes sense to turn this override into a mixin and a setting, so it does not have to be defined on every page model and the redirect host can be differentiated between environments.

You could also use the same logic of overriding the `serve()` method to redirect to any other location you may choose.