# How do we handle 'View Live' while creating a page/child page in a decoupled wagtail project?

Tags: django, reactjs, wagtail

I have a decoupled wagtail project in which front-end is served by ReactJS. Front-end build files are served from /proj_dir/frontend/react and is defined in /proj_dir/settings/base.py as

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'proj_dir/frontend/react', "build", "static"),
        ]
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 

TEMPLATES = [
  {
      'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projdir/frontend/react')],
      'APP_DIRS': True,
      'OPTIONS': {
          'context_processors': [
          'django.template.context_processors.debug',
          'django.template.context_processors.request',
          'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
          'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                        'wagtail.contrib.settings.context_processors.settings',
            ],
         },
      },
   ]
```

So when I 'build' the react application, this frontend application is served on 'python runserver'

1. How can I handle the 'View Live' scenario when we create a
   page/child page in this case.
2. In order to reduce the development time is it possible not to write template files for each pagetypes?

Answer (score 2):

See this answer for overriding the URL used by 'view live':

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48470772/181793

In addition, `wagtail-headless-preview` is designed to improve the editor experience with headless sites like yours:

https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail-headless-preview

This approach works wherever your site is hosted - whether it's part of your Django / Wagtail app or somewhere completely separate, like AWS S3 or Netlify.

You don't need to write template files for pages which will be served 'headlessly'.

Comment: I have a site setup with a Wagtail backend and a Gatsby frontend. I do use `wagtail-headless-preview`. It works for the preview, but the `Live` links in the admin result in "Template not found" or "404" error (depending on DEBUG setting). Should `wagtail-headless-preview` also take care of that? Did I set something up wrong?